Finding angle from point a to point b given grid coordinates in MGRS format
SI mils to Military Mils and the distance formula
I have a question about SI mils vs Nato Mils and this looks like a great place to ask for help.
Im currently in the military and am a mortar, we use a certain item called a plotting board to find how to aim our guns using two coordinates called MGRS (Military Grid Reference System) as well as the direction or angle from my location to the target. I recently learned there is a math method where i can take both locations in their 10 digit grids (ex 12345 67890 and 23456 78910) and subtract both eastings (first number) and their northings (second number) and that will give me a difference in location via right/left and up/down that I can then use Pythagorean theorem to find the hypotenuse or true distance from x to y.
Then i found you can use some trig to find the angle from x to y, i was told that you can use a function on a calculator called atan that will solve it for you in radians. The only issue for me is that 1 im stupid and didnt pay attention in class to figure out how to use trig at all. Lastly SI miliradians are different than military mils in the fact that a full circle in SI is 6238 mils and a military circle is 6400 mils.
Is there a way i can use this trig function to find the angle from x to y in SI miliradians and then convert it to military mils and have it be within 10 mils of the correct answer on the fly?

Indeed, if you have two points $X(x_1, y_1)$ and $Y(x_2, y_2)$, the distance can be found using Pythagoras: $d=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$.
The tangent of angle can be found using $\arctan$ function: $\theta=\arctan{\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}}$. Keep in mind that atan/arctan result will be in the interval $-\frac{\pi}{2} < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$ so you need some additional calculations to find the actual angle $\phi$.  Something like:
\begin{cases}
    \phi = \theta & \text{if } x_2 >x_1,y_2 > y_1 \\ % & is your "\tab"-like command (it's a tab alignment character)
    \phi= \pi + \theta & \text{if } x_2 <x_1,y_2 > y_1 \\
\phi= \pi + \theta & \text{if } x_2 <x_1,y_2 < y_1 \\
\phi= 2\pi + \theta  & \text{if } x_2 >x_1,y_2 < y_1
\end{cases}
You also need to take account edge cases, such as $x_1=x_2, y_1=y_2$

Would this work when trying to find the direction you are looking given you are one of the coordinates and you are looking at the second set of coordinates. The distance formula is amazing but im just curious as using atan gives me some angles in degrees that dont work as a "math circle" is different from a "real circle" that works like a compass. When you go to -90 on a compass its just 270° but -90 on a "math circle like this gives you an error from my understanding.

@programmerinneed: these calculations will work if you are at point $X$ and the target is at point $Y$. They will produce a positive angle in the range from $0$ to $2\pi$ radians.  Your example with $-90^\circ$ falls into the last bucket so $\phi=2\pi+(-\frac{\pi}{2})=\frac{3\pi}{2}$. Obviously if you are at point $Y$ and target is at point $X$ it will be different.

Im having an issue where the X¹ is 00350 and the X² is 97400. Im doing what i was told by others to add a 1 infront of X¹ to make it not a stupidly wrong answer yet im still getting the wrong angle. Because im using NATO mils i have to change from degrees/radians into Nato mils which is different from milliradians as nato mils are just more simple for idiots to understand. Do you know if there is a fix for this at all? I can give a more indepth example if need be

@Masterhcker23: you do not need to change $x_1$. Give me the data you are using and the expected result. Converting to Nato mil is not an issue..

The data im using to test this theory is -> 1) X(1398078070) Y(1561080030) desired answer is 0710 ±5 mils Nato, distance is 2550 ±25 . 2) X(0035054480) Y(9740056200) desired answer is 5337 ±5 mils Nato and distance is 3400 ± 25

i found the reason it wasnt working. I was using MGRS which is an east facing coordinate system while trying to use a plotting board which is always north facing, once i figured out that i needed to convert the angle east (radians)-(π/2) i was getting the correct answer within 2 mils every time unless the grid was like 0035064480 and 9740056200. With those it was about 160° off everytime
